# Reducing a DataSource

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

In my data structure I am querying my database and getting a `DataSource.Factory` which has a list of rows that I need to reduce and create a new `DataSource.Factory`. Now currently to transform the data I am using the `map` function but because map produces a `1:1` result I am facing the issue of duplicates. I need to reduce the data and create another datasource. Can anyone suggest me anything to suit this kind of requirement?

Thanks in advance.

`Code Sample`

```
class A {
    ...
    List<B> listOfBs;
    ...
}

class B {
   ...
}
```

Now I have a searchDAO which does join on A and B.

So `searchDAO.findEveryWhere()` will give me rows from Table A and Table B which is packed into one `DataSource.Factory` of `SearchEntities`

Now I am doing `datasource.map(new Function<SearchEntity, MergedEntity>(){...})` which indeed returns me another `DataSource.Factory`.

But I need to reduce and create MergeEntity not the equal amount of MergedEntities. Because that mapped datasource is being used in a ListAdapter which is getting duplicate MergedEntities just because the map function will create same amount of MergedEntities that is there in the SearchEntity Datasource.

Comment: I have n number of rows in a datasource and I want to reduce that to m number of rows where (m <= n). How can I do that? And I am using PagedListAdapter.

Comment: @pskink can you provide an example for the same.. because I was trying to map one livedata to another but it actually creates same amount of rows

Comment: Mine is two level filter... This is single level... Basically my dao returns a livedata of entity a and I want to map that to another entity and create another livedata